# How to remove the redundancy?

Tags: python, oop

```py
class Document:

    def __init__(self, x:str, y:int):
        self.name = x
        self.value = y

    @classmethod
    def in_progress_document(cls): #a document that is not yet named
        return cls("unnamed",0)

    @classmethod   
    def unknown_document(cls): #a document whose name is unknown 
        return cls("unknown",0)
```

Is there some redundancy between the two class method in the previous code? If so, how to remove it in a clean way?

PS: I really need this distinction between `unnamed` and `unknown` -- The `unnamed` is a document in progress, it can be named later but the `unknown` is a finished document without a title, it will not have one in the future.

Comment: You may be able to use an enum or something but I personally don't see any issue here. Maybe another class method that you pass in the "error code" to keep things concise

Comment: What do you mean by "Maybe another class method that you pass in the "error code" to keep things concise "  ?

Answer (score 1):

In the code below I've inserted a new and single class method *baseConstructor*. *in_progress_document* and *unknown_document* are now static methods and do not have any parameter. They call *baseConstructor* passing the desired name.

```
class Document:

    def __init__(self, x:str, y:int):
        self.name = x
        self.value = y

    @classmethod
    def baseConstructor(cls, msg):
        return cls(msg, 0)

    @staticmethod
    def in_progress_document(): #a document that is not yet named
        return Document.baseConstructor("unnamed")

    @staticmethod   
    def unknown_document(): #a document whose name is unknown 
        return Document.baseConstructor("unknown")
```

Comment: Why would you consider this more readable and less redundant?

Comment: I would say these should still be classmethods, calling `cls.baseConstrutor`, you could then only override `baseConstructor` in any subclass. I would maybe choose the name `zeroed(cls, msg)` or something.

Comment: Well, i was focusing at redudancy, not readability. However, the way you call methods is still the same. Moreover, *cls(msg, 0)* appears only once and *msg* is the portion that varies (*value* 0 is not repeated). Since you have just 2 fields, it's not easily realizable. But, if you had more fields, then it'd be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

hope I understand your problem correctly, isnt it supposed to be like this

```
class Document:

    def __init__(self, x:str, y:int):
        self.name = x
        self.value = y

    @classmethod
    def in_progress_document(cls, val): #a document that is not yet named
        return cls("unnamed", val) # value instead of 0 --> to avoid redundancy?

    @classmethod   
    def unknown_document(cls, val) : #a document whose name is unknown 
        return cls("unknown", val)
```

then create the object like

```
normal_doc = Document('I am Normal', 100)
not_yet_named = Document.in_progress_document(10)
no_title_doc = Document.unknown_document(100)
```